# Not able to move focus from Current window to a popup generated from that window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a MVVM application where I am creating  a popup using button click. My end goal is to move focus from the current window to newly generated popup.

Button click will hit a command which will set SetFlag bool value to True and pop up will be displayed.

The problem is when I Tab the controls it remains on current window.
Please suggest me how to shift focus to the popup window.

XAML code

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </TextBox>
            <Label x:Name="lblAddress" Content="Address" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path =Address , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Width="100" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Content="Update"  
               Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}">
        </Button>

        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding SetFlag}"  Width="300" Height="300"  Name="StartMenuPopup" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnUpdate}" >
            <Grid Background="LightGray" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Background="Black" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
                    <Button x:Name="closeBtn" Grid.Row="0" Content="Close" Width="50px" Height="30px" Margin="5"></Button>
                </Border>
                <Button x:Name="testBtn" Grid.Row="1" Content="Test" Width="50px" Height="30px" Margin="5"></Button>
                <Label Name="lblAge" Grid.Row="2" Margin="30,5" Focusable="True">Age</Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAge" Grid.Row="2" Width="100px" Height="20px" Margin="5"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel Code

```
 private ICommand mUpdater;
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (mUpdater == null)
                    mUpdater = new PersonCommand(SetFlagStatus);
                return mUpdater;
            }
            set
            {
                mUpdater = value;
            }
        }

        private bool _setFlag = false;
        public bool SetFlag
        {
            get { return _setFlag; }
            set
            {
                _setFlag = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SetFlag));
            }
        }

        private void SetFlagStatus()
        {

                    SetFlag = !SetFlag;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a view responsibility which will require reference to that textbox or some very complicated code.

I would recommend simple.

You can try the Popup’s Opened event:

```
    private void StartMenuPopup_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          txtAge.Focus();
    }
```

I think that should fire after the content is rendered. If not then you could use dispatcher to queue setting focus.